# How to compare and count the high/low value using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

The following is a `minute` based `df`:

```
GMT_Time                Open
2017-01-03 07:00:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 07:01:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 07:02:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 07:03:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 07:04:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 07:05:00     5.2475
2017-01-03 07:06:00     5.2475
.....
```

I want to use thefirst `GMT_Time` `Open` `Value(07:00:00)` and get the `COUNT` of values that are `Low` and `High` compared to `07:00:00` `Open` `Value` for that particular day.

My new `df` should look like this:

- It is a `Day` based dataset
- `Open` value is the value we used to compare
- `High` is the count of values that is greater than the `Open` at `07:00:00`
- `Low` is the count of values that is less than the `Open` at `07:00:00`
- `Same` is the count of values that is equal to the `Open` at `07:00:00`

  ```
  GMT_Time                Open     High     Low    Same   
  2017-01-03 07:00:00     5.2475   234      346    32 
  2017-01-04 07:00:00     6.2475   234      346    12 
  2017-01-05 07:00:00     4.2475   234      346    14
  ```

**What did I do?**

I am able to find the `High` and `low` value for a given day by doing:

```
df.groupby(df['GMT_Time'].dt.floor('D')).Open.agg(['min','max'])
```

but I am trying to find the total count of values that are `High` or `low` compared to the `07:00:00` `Open` value.

How do I work on this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with `transform`

```
df['DIFF']=df.groupby(df.GMT_Time.dt.date,sort=False).Open.transform('first')
pd.crosstab([df.GMT_Time.dt.date,df.DIFF], np.sign(df.Open-df.DIFF))
col_0              0.0
GMT_Time   DIFF       
2017-01-03 5.2475    7
```

Comment: Thank you for composing the answer. It does not seem to work properly. Also, we need to take a count only after we figure out if the value is `Low` or `High` compared to the first value at `07:00:00` of a given day.

Comment: @floss ha there are typo should be first

Comment: Thank you, now it does not give the `7:00:00` and the `Open` value at `7:00:00`

Comment: @floss that is easy to add `pd.crosstab([df.GMT_time.dt.date,s], np.sign(df.Open-s)).reset_index()`

Comment: It does not work. It creates 3 `rows` for the `-1` `0` `1` column

Comment: Let me show your whole code match your output @floss

Comment: How can I rename the column name `-1` `0`  `1` ?

Comment: @floss adding .rename(columns={-1:'H',0:'same',1:'low'})

Comment: I wanted to confirm that `-1` is `high` and `1` is `low`

Comment: @floss yes, that is

Comment: But this says it the other way: https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html  `-1 if x < 0, 0 if x==0, 1 if x > 0`

Comment: @flossf I am using open - current , if lower than 0 mean the current is higher /

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198061/discussion-between-floss-and-wenyoben).

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help. I just want to confirm 100% that it is taking the `7:00:00` `Open` value and then count the number of value that each-day which are `high`, `low` and 'same'

Comment: @floss current is the time for incremental time and open is 7:00